# Ceiling light/fan remote problem

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, fans

I have a ceiling light/fan controlled by remote only - no light switch or pull cables. Now the remote receiver is broken and the company doesn't make the replacement part anymore.
So in buying a new ceiling fan, do I have to buy one powered by remote? Or will a light switch need to be installed if I want one controlled by light switch? Is there a chance my current fan receiver is bypassing the light switch that should control it?
I'm in the dark here. DIY beginner.
Thanks everyone

Comment: You said the light was controlled without light switch or pull cables.  But, is there a switch on the wall or not?  Bypassing a switch is trivial (just wirenut the switch wires together).  But if there's physically no switch, this is a much more complicated problem.  Is there a blank plate (behind which you'd find wirenutted wires) or a switch in the room that doesn't do anything?  If there's no switch, you may be stuck with remote and/or pull-chain operation without a lot of sheetrock and drill work.

Comment: There are several switches on my bedroom walls which control other lighting fixtures / electrical outlets.

Comment: So if a light switch is bypassed - just take the light switch out of the wall and see if any of the wires are not connected?

Comment: What you would find is a disconnected light switch (no wires to it).  Behind the switch you'll find two wires tied together with a wire nut.  This creates the bypass.  (If there are more than two wires, say that in a comment as more instructions may be needed.)  If just the two connected wires are there, turn off the breaker (important!), remove the wire nut and reconnect the wires to the switch in any order and you're good to replace the fan with anything you want.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch and fan boxes?

Comment: Even better... check the canopy of the existing fan for the remote model. There is a good chance it’s just wired in ahead of the fan at the ceiling.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look behind some of the potential light switches and in the canopy of the existing ceiling fan. Probably Saturday morning. Thanks for the instructions!

Comment: The possibility is that there is a fan switch - a blank plate is on the switch covering or you have a useless switch somewhere , of course you could also have a multi switch that was converted to a single switch.

Comment: I know this may be a dumb comment... But did you try *replacing the batteries* in the remote. I've had many calls about people's remote controlled ceiling fans non working, only to find they forgot to check the batteries before they called me... Even cases where I ask them first and they tell me "yes", only to find that they somehow "thought" they did

Answer (score 1):

Some fan manufacturers make after-market remote controls that can be attached to non-remote-controlled fans. (I have 2 installed.) Here is a link to one made by Progress Lighting. https://www.progresslightingexperts.com/lighting/7-196-826-0-220446/Progress_Air-Pro---Fan-Light-Remote-Control-P2618-01.htm. While my fan was also switched (just on/off), it's light and speed were controlled by pull cords. I put the remotes in to allow control by remote instead of pull cord. Just make sure there is room in the fan for the receiver.